# How to create a LWUIT Image object from a MIDP native image?

Tags: lwuit

In the documentation of LWUIT there is the createImage method which creates a LWUIT Image object from a MIDP native image ( public static Image createImage(java.lang.Object nativeImage) ).

I want to know how to implement the java.lang.Object parameter in order to set a MIDP native image as the parameter of the method ? For example I capture a photo from the camera ( `byte[] rawImage = myVideoControl.getSnapshot(null);` ) and I create the image file in the filesystem :

```
myFileConnection = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///"+pRoot+photoDirectory+"/"+photoName);
```

`myFileConnection.openOutputStream().write(rawImage);`

. So how to pass the Object parameter to the createImage method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Image img = Image.createImage(myFileConnection.openInputStream());
```

EDIT:
see

```
javax.microedition.lcdui.Image img = javax.microedition.lcdui.Image.createImage("/images/card.png");
            com.sun.lwuit.Image ii = com.sun.lwuit.Image.createImage(img);
```

Comment: There is already a CreateImage method with java.io.InputStream as a parameter in the documentation , and there is also the java.lang.Object also as parameter ! So what is the difference between them ? LWUIT has its reasons to put these two methods ! So how to pass the parameter when it is expected to be java.lang.Object ?

Comment: Use to pass Native MIDP Image object `javax.microedition.lcdui.Image`, its converting image to lwuit image

Comment: There is a java package conflict error when I try to work with MIDP and LWUIT Image's ! So how to call them separately ?

Comment: @Andy Frédéric : see my edit, do you wanna same or else? its working fine